# Notification Lights On Desktop Case

Tags: motherboard, case

One more question about the Corsair Carbide Series SPEC-03 Black Steel ATX Mid Tower Gaming Case - the activity light will light up and display red, and both the power button and the reset button work.  However, neither the power or reset button are illuminated red, and they seem to give the appearance that they should be.

Question being on this case should the power and reset button be backlit red?  Or did I possibly faulty connect the connectors to the motherboard?

Comment: I don't think they have backlight. I've watched several videos and none of them seemed to have the power/reset button backlit. It seems kind of strange to me because the Spec-02 did have backlit power/reset buttons.

Comment: @DrZoo - most desktops I have had, have backlit buttons which is why I was wanting to check and confirm I did not improperly wire something.

Comment: I agree that most do have the backlight buttons too. But in this case, it seems they are not backlit on this case